# Copy a windows folder with its permissions but without overwritting the content

Tags: windows, batch-file, permissions, directory

I want to copy a folder with its permissions but without copying its content. So an example:

```
C:\pictures and it has cat photos in it
```

I want to copy only the permission to

```
D:\pictures (has other pictures)
```

and I want to copy it to

```
E:\pictures (this folder is not existing)
```

I tried it with `robocopy` and with `icacls`. But I am not able to restore the data with icacls:

```
icacls C:\pictures /save ntfspermissions.txt /c
icacls D:\pictures /restore C:\ntfspermissions.txt
```

and it just says: `1 error`.

In robocopy I tried it with the parameter "`/COPY:SAO`". But it is not working too. It only works with "`/MIR`" but if I do that, I have the content copied too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use get-acl and set-acl :

```
$acl=get-acl -path C:\pictures
set-acl -path d:\pictures -AclObject $acl
New-Item -ItemType directory -Name pictures -Path e:\
set-acl -path e:\pictures -AclObject $acl
```

More detailed answer by Don Jones : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.02.powershell.aspx